# What class does a JavaScript async function belong to?

Tags: javascript

If I try in Google Chrome's dev tool:

```js
fn = async () => {
  await new Promise((res) => setTimeout(res, 3000));
  return 123;
};

fn.constructor           // => ƒ AsyncFunction() { [native code] }

fn.__proto__.__proto__ === Function.prototype           // => true

AsyncFunction            // => Uncaught ReferenceError: AsyncFunction is not defined
```

From the above, it seems `fn` is an `AsyncFunction` instance, and `AsyncFunction` "is-a" `Function`, but `AsyncFunction` doesn't exist.

How can this be understood? (and what class does `fn` belong to?)

Comment: see [AsyncFunction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/AsyncFunction) which notes *'that AsyncFunction is not a global object'* but can be obtained with the following: `const AsyncFunction = async function () {}.constructor;`

Comment: it seems like this question and answer can be a standalone Q&A on SO, rather than getting closed as a duplicate (the linked post on SO for closing this question doesn't really answer this question)

Comment: Either way it is unambiguously answered by even a cursory reading of the documentation.

Comment: "*but `AsyncFunction` doesn't exist.*" - you mean there is no such global variable, not that the `AsyncFunction` constructor does not exist. So what? It seems you already understood this fine.

Comment: The duplicate already has an excellent answer which perfectly explains the situation with a lot of background, even if the question comes at it from a different angle. No reason *not* to close this as a dupe.